# Quotient of Confluent Hypergeometric Functions of the 1st Kind

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I want to solve the following problem for x:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\ e^{-\beta_{1}x}\,{_{1}}F_{1}[-\alpha_{1};-\alpha_{3};\beta_{3}x]=0
\end{equation}

where, $\alpha_{1},\alpha_{3}, \beta_{1}, \beta_{3}, >0$ and $x\geq0$.

Taking the derivative I get

\begin{equation}
\frac{\alpha_{1}}{\alpha_{3}}\beta_{3}e^{-\beta_{1}x}\,{_{1}}F_{1}[-\alpha_{1}+1;-\alpha_{3}+1;\beta_{3}x]
=
\beta_{1}e^{-\beta_{1}x}\,{_{1}}F_{1}[-\alpha_{1};-\alpha_{3};\beta_{3}x]
\end{equation}

Rearranging terms,

\begin{equation}
\frac{{_{1}}F_{1}[-\alpha_{1};-\alpha_{3};\beta_{3}x]}{{_{1}}F_{1}[-\alpha_{1}+1;-\alpha_{3}+1;\beta_{3}x]}
-
\frac{\alpha_{1}\beta_{3}}{\alpha_{3}\beta_{1}}
=0
\end{equation}

Not 100% sure I know how to move forward. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware of the Kummer transformation, by any chance? Nevertheless, it is not possible in general to represent such a quotient by another hypergeometric function, but you might be interested in its [continued fraction expansion](http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.5).

Comment: @J.M I do not necessarily need to represent the quotient as another hypergeometric function.  I am just looking to simplify it.  Since the hypergeometric function is a polynomial, isn't their a way to represent the quotient of two of them as a power series?  Also, I have the NIST handbook and am taking a look at the continued fraction bit you posted.

Comment: "the hypergeometric function is a polynomial" - then it would seem to me that you had neglected to mention that the numerator parameter is a nonpositive integer. That is a special case that requires a different way of handling.

Comment: Please excuse me for the confusion, the parameters $\alpha_{1},\alpha_{3},\beta_{1},\beta_{3}$ are all positive.  All four parameters can be integers or of the for $(2n+1)/2$.

Comment: Yes, so $-\alpha_1$ is then a nonpositive integer, no? That would be why you get a degeneration of the Kummer function to a polynomial, and that is a case that, as I said, requires special treatment. I believe Yudell Luke treated this in one of his books, but I do not have his books on hand at the moment.

Comment: $-\alpha_{1}$ can be either a non-positive integer or can be of the form $(2n+1)/2$ where $n=0,1,2,\dots$.

Comment: In the half-integer case, it should not degenerate to a polynomial, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: In any event, the general formula for the coefficient of a ratio of two series will involve the so-called Bell polynomial; unless you have a system that supports them, they are rather unwieldy to manipulate. Why do you need that $d_n$ anyway?

Comment: You are correct. For the half-integer case the hypergeometric function is a polynomial of infinite terms. For the integer case it will be a polynomial with a finite number of terms.  I updated the post with a link to a general solution for the problem that should help find the solution

Comment: Your "closed form" is precisely the ratio of two hypergeometric functions that you started with; what more do you want?

Comment: One really does not expect a general transcendental equation to have a (simple) closed form solution.

Comment: @J.M. You are right.  I needed to work out the non-degenerate case to see your point. Could you please explain the process for the degenerate case (i.e. $-\alpha_{1}\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$)?  I know you mentioned a book by Yudell Luke. I will add the process for the degenerate case to the answer I started.

Comment: I am currently far away from my books, but look up *The Special Functions and Their Approximations*.

Comment: @J.M. I will thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a\neq -1,-2,-3,\dots,$ and $a-b\neq 0,1,2,\dots,$ then the ratio of confluent hypergeometric functions can be expressed as the continued fraction:

\begin{equation}
  \frac{{_{1}}F_{1}(a,b,z)}{{_{1}}F_{1}(a+1,b+1,z)}=1+\cfrac{u_{1}z}{1+\cfrac{u_{2}z}{1+\cdots}}
\end{equation}

where, $u_{2n+1}=\frac{a-b-n}{(b+2n)(b+2n+1)}$, and $u_{2n}=\frac{a+n}{(b+2n-1)(b+2n)}$.

This continued fraction can be truncated at any $u_{n}$ which yields a ratio of polynomials in $z$. Taking the quotient of the polynomials and solving for z will give an approximation to the root in question.  Truncating at larger $n$ will yield a closer approximation.